How to convert to BCNF
I need some help converting this set of my database into BCNF.
If H = {A, B, C} and A -> BC and C -> A, how would I make this BCNF?

Instead of H, You can create 2 tables to achieve BCNF such;
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    C TEXT,     -- C is the primary key
    B TEXT,     -- B is determined by C
    PRIMARY KEY (C)
);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
    C TEXT,     -- C is the primary key
    A TEXT,     -- A is determined by C
    PRIMARY KEY (C)
);

